# csv writer ignore certain values

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

Let's say that I want the built in python csv writer to ignore certain string values in array (place no value between commas in output). For instance,

```
my_list = [4, 'foo', 'close', 9, 0]

csv output => 4, ,'close', 9, 0
```

I would provide a parameter 'foo' that would designate to be ignored by the writer, is this possible? If so, could somebody help on the implementation?

Comment: Could you please fix your output? There is a stray quotation mark and I'm not sure if you want `', '` or `','` as delimiter

Comment: Do you really want the representation of the string (`'close'`) instead of just `close`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> my_list = [4, 'foo', 'close', 9, 0]
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as fout:
        w = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')
        w.writerow([x if x != 'foo' else ' ' for x in my_list])

>>> print open('test.csv').read()
4, ,close,9,0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, if you have a 2D list of rows to write:

```
lines = [[4, 'foo', 'close', 9, 0], [5, 'foo', 'close', 9, 0]]

import csv
with open("outfile.csv", "wb") as outf:
    w = csv.writer(outf)
    for line in lines:
        w.writerow(["" if e == "foo" else e for e in line])
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on python 3. It raises the error: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to do replacements within the list:

```
map(lambda x : str(x) if x != 'foo' else ' ', my_list)
```

and just do a `join` to create the output string:

```
','.join(map(lambda x : str(x) if x != 'foo' else ' ', my_list))
```

Comment: note that list comprehensions are usually considered better style than `map` `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ignored_strings = {'foo', 'ignored2', 'ignored3'}

my_list_filtered = [value if value not in ignored_strings else '' for value in my_list]
```

That replaces each value you want to ignore by an empty string. You can then use the csv writer to print out the new list.

You could also simply remove values you don't want from a list using an 'if' statement at the end of the list comprehension, depending on what you want your output to look like.

Comment: If you're going to use this method, `ignored_strings` should be a set